# How to get ratios from a deformed cube for a trilinear interpolation?

Tags: c++, math, interpolation

I have a cube with known vertices position (bottom back left vertice, top front right, etc...).  I also have a known center, and a known point.  I want to express that point as a ratio of X/Y/Z of the lattices of that cube to use as a trilinear interpolation.  So, for a given point, it has an X/Y/Z ratios that can be then be used to recalculate new positions when the cube is deformed.

So, my question is : What is the method to find the inverse trilinear interpolation to find out a point's ratio?  Basically, from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation, I want a mean to find xd, yd and zd from a known point, and a deformed cube.

The closest I have come to finding a solution is http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/winddocs/utilities/b4wind_guide/trilinear.html but I am not sure I understand it properly.  Reading it, it seems that they guesstimate it a/b/g to be at 0, then run it through their formula, hopes it gets the proper answer.  If not, calculate a delta from the expected vs received solution.  If after 20 runs they don't have a good enough solution, they simply give up.

Comment: Do you know the (forward) deformation model for each point of the cube ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an easy problem if you know how to relate cube displacements to a strain measure.

You don't say if the deformations are small or large.

The most general solution would be to assume a large strain measure based on original, undefored geometry: Green-Lagrange large strain tensor.

You can substitute the interpolation functions into the strain displacement relations to get what you want.